# How to detect names as entities using LUIS in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using luis.ai which is offered as a part of Microsoft Cognitive Services, in my project. I have a requirement of detecting names using LUIS. For the same, I have been using the phrase list feature. I have added some names in the list. But as we all know, the names list is never exhaustive. So, no matter how many names I add, since they don't have a specific pattern, when I test with some new names, the entity detection fails. I want to know if there's any other way in which we can have LUIS detect names of people.

Please let me know if you have a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

LUIS could be used to recognize and extract intents and entities from utterances, but based on my experience, it might not be 100% intelligent to identify person’s name, because person’s name could be anything.

As you did, adding not well-recognized names in phrase list could be as a solution. Besides, this github issue:[Identifying the Names from the sentence using LUIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2007) discussed a similar question, and as cahann mentioned, you can add and label more example utterances that contain not well-recognized name to make your LUIS app recognize Names better.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Fei han :). I already looked at the other github issue you talked about. It still doesn't solve the problem of luis not being able to detect a new name which is not in the phrase list

Comment: @LeelaManasBayireddy unfortunately LUIS does not perform semantic analysis, meaning the word "Bill" isn't interpreted as either an invoice-like object or as a proper noun. Through further training it might be possible to train LUIS to have a rough understanding for this utterance "My name is [$Name]", but it will not have perfect accuracy in picking up that the fourth token is supposed to be a name value.